# How do I turn on the Steam Link without a Steam Controller?

Tags: steam-link

I have a PS4 controller connected to my Steam Link.  If I choose "turn off" from the Steam Link menu options, how do I, uh, turn it back on?

Is unplugging it and plugging it back in seriously the only option?

With a Steam Controller you can hit the big button in the center of the controller, but that doesn't seem to work with a PS4 controller.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work with the Xbox 360 controller.

Comment: Sounds like something that would have to be set up on the driver's side - to detect the Ps button (or giant 'X' on the 360 controller) being pressed. Favoriting because I'm interested as well.

Comment: Have you looked at this [steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/490125737456641019/) thread yet?

Comment: @BlueRaja - Are you using any third party tools to have your PS4 controller work on PC? Everywhere I've looked online it seems that it's not natively supported and that you may have to have it set to emulate an Xbox 360 controller

Comment: @Robotnik: Huh?  Steam Link runs SteamOS, it is not a PC.  That said, you're incorrect - PS4 controllers are supported on PC without special drivers.  I think you're thinking of PS3 controllers, which do require [custom drivers](http://motioninjoy.en.uptodown.com/).  Or maybe you're confused because a lot of games only support XBox 360 controllers, so a lot of people use custom PS4 controller drivers (such as [DS4Windows](http://ds4windows.com/)) to emulate them.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't sure if the device was Windows or SteamOS - I was just trying to clarify whether you were using any third-party tools which may be causing an issue, or whether you did have it configured to emulate a 360 controller or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of several updates ago, turning on the Steam Link now works correctly with a wireless PS4 controller.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that yes, the only way to turn it on is to unplug it then plug it back in. There are a few threads on the Steam Community discussing this, [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/483368526581883814/), [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/483367798520926759/), and [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/490125737456641019/) (last one already mentioned by aman207).

It seems that, as described in the first thread, "the whole turning on and off thing is a bit of a mess at the moment". Speculated by many of the posters on the threads, perhaps there are bugs regarding turning on and off the system with those controllers, or maybe it is simply not implemented yet and will come with future updates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the only way.

When you press the home button it sends a signal asking if the ps4 is still on if it gets that signal that it will turn on. Since it is not talking to the ps4 then it will not turn back on because the steam link does not send the same signal as what the ps4 would

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or is it just conjecture?  My understanding is that the PS4 controller fully supports the bluetooth standard, so it _should_ be possible for it to turn on the system...

Comment: I know because i have one and that is the only way sadly maybe valve might make a update to make it work but for know that's it